# AngularJS Directive doesn't update scope for callback

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am using directives to create a component library in AngularJS 1.5. Hence, my directives need to have isolate scopes.

Some of my directives have callbacks so you can pass in a function to get invoked by the directive. However, when that callback is invoked by the directive, it doesn't seem like the changes to $scope attributes are fully updated like I would expect them to be.

Here is a Plunker that shows this behavior:
http://embed.plnkr.co/Rg15FHtHgCDExxOYNwNa/

Here is what the code looks like:

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('Controller', ['$scope',function($scope) {
        // initialize the value to something obvious
        $scope.clickersValue = "BEFORE";

        // when this call back is called we would expect the value to be updated by updated by the directive
        $scope.clickersCallback = function() {
        //$scope.$apply(); // $apply is not allowed here
        $scope.clickersValueRightAfterCall = $scope.clickersValue;
        console.log("clickersCallback: scope.clickersValue", $scope.clickersValue);
    };
  }
]);

app.directive('clicker', [function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    template: '<div ng-click="clicked()">click me!</div>',
    controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.clicked = function() {
        console.log("you clicked me.");
        $scope.newValue = 'VALID';
        $scope.myUpdate();
      }
    }],
    scope: {
      "newValue": "=",
      "myUpdate": "&"
    }
  };
}]);
</script>
```

So when clickersCallback gets invoked the clickersValue attribute still has the old value. I have tried using $scope.$apply but of course it isn't allowed when another update is happening. I also tried using controller_bind but got the same effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the code inside `clickersCallback` function in a `$timeout` function.

```
$timeout(function() {
    $scope.clickersValueRightAfterCall = $scope.clickersValue;
    console.log("clickersCallback: scope.clickersValue", $scope.clickersValue); 
});
```

[Updated plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/F5KcF9O4fFxLzRxcmDjI/)

> The $timeout does not generate error like „$digest already in progress“ because $timeout tells Angular that after the current cycle, there is a timeout waiting and this way it ensures that there will not any collisions between digest cycles and thus output of $timeout will execute on a new $digest cycle.
>   [source](http://www.codingeek.com/angularjs/angular-js-apply-timeout-digest-evalasync/)

**Edit 1:** As the OP said below, the user of the directive should not have to write any "special" code in his callback function.

To achieve this behavior I changed the $timeout from de controller to the directive.

**Controller callback function (*without changes*):**

```
$scope.clickersCallback = function() {
    $scope.clickersValueRightAfterCall = $scope.clickersValue;
    console.log("clickersCallback: scope.clickersValue", $scope.clickersValue);
};
```

**Directive code (*inject $timeout in the directive*):**

```
 $scope.clicked = function() {
     console.log("you clicked me.");
     $scope.newValue = 'VALID';
     $timeout(function() {
         $scope.myUpdate();
     });
 }
```

[Updated plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/4ZuiTsDL3KGUX9ZN1NH2/)

Comment: Gabriel, Thanks for the creative approach. But, this requires the user of the directive to do something special in their code. I am really looking for a way that the directive user can just use an expression like we do in ng-click. But, I still up-voted your suggestion.

Comment: Maybe you can wrap the `$scope.myUpdate();` call inside the `$timeout` in the directive. Is that what you want? [plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/4ZuiTsDL3KGUX9ZN1NH2/)

Comment: Yes! That is exactly what I wanted! I tried that after your suggestion but I must have gotten it wrong in my code somehow. Can you post that as an answer so I can mark it answered? Can't thank you enough, this is great.